# NVIDIA card not detected, but its HDMI port works

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-geforce

My first post, I'll do my best to not waste everyone's time.
I have installed a new GeForce GTX 1060 on my Ubuntu-using machine. The system is still using the motherboard AMD Pitcairn card, though, without detecting the new device.

```
$ lspci |grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn PRO [Radeon HD 7850 / R7 265 / R9 270 1024SP]
```

However, here is the interesting part: the monitor is currently connected through HDMI... through the new card. So... it's not visible in the system, but it's working? I have searched through similar answers, but have found nothing.

If it helps, here is my motherboard info:

```
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASRock
    Product Name: B75 Pro3
    Version:                       
    Serial Number: E80-28002301823
    Asset Tag:                       
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis:                       
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: 
Here is some of what I've tried already, without success:

- Disabling Safe Boot in BIOS
- Also in BIOS, setting Primary Graphics Adapter to PCI Express
- Simply installing the proper nVidia driver, out of desperation

Comment: What does `lspci | grep 3D` tell you? Please add it to your question.

Comment: Well, it returns... absolutely nothing :-)